# Deactivate the captcha after correctly answering it

Tags: discussion, captcha

Why if I have answered a captcha two or three times does the system continue to tell me that it is probable that I am a robot when I modify an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the captcha is a PITA, but the only answer you will get is that it will never be removed.

Your account could be compromised at any time after all.

Comment: Ok, I haven´t thought about this case ;)

Comment: I don't think of the captcha as a PITA.  I think of spam as a PITA.

Comment: @btk: You also don't edit 20-30 posts in 5 minutes.

Comment: @Rich B: Thank goodness for that!